# What defines a ClickOnce application and how does it allow for certificate renewal?

Tags: certificate, clickonce

I'm trying to understand what properties uniquely identifies a ClickOnce application and, as a result of that, makes it impossible for someone else to actually make "the same" application as me ("forging"). From this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2006/04/20/580223.aspx I get that the identity of the application is the combination of application name, public key token, language and processor architecture as defined by the applicationIdentity inside the deployment manifest. This makes sense to me: From what I understand, the public key token is determined by the key pair used to sign the manifest which means that "making the same application" as me requires access to the key pair I use.

In the article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx I read that it is possible to change the key pair ("certificate") used for signing the application (manifests). If I understand things right changing the key pair will change the public key token which, by the definition of application identity from above, would make the resulting application a new application. But I thought one of the points of the article was to say that under the right circumstances you CAN change the certificate without making a new application?

In other words: How does the definition of the application identity in the first article go together with the possibility of changing to a new certificate stated by the second article?